# Detect USB key/drive using PHP (client side installation)

Tags: php, usb, client-side-scripting

first of all, I want to be clear on this point, the PHP script will run on the client side (not server side, I know it's impossible!).

How can PHP detect USB key/USB drive when it is plugged on the USB port?

Or, how can it detest USB when running the command (not at the time we plug it on the computer) if it's more possible...

It's under windows. Under MAC should be good too but I really need that for Windows.

Any idea ? using a command prompt and analysing retrieved informations (ignoring cd/dvd drive then let the user choose)

Don't know if I'm enought clear here but give your idea and let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure PHP is right tool for this task, however you can try to setup trigger in Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a combination of one of the `exec()` family of functions with whatever command-line utility Windows has for viewing currently attached devices(`fsutil`, `fsinfo`, `fdisk`?).

Comment: fsinfo and fdisk are not a command under the CLI. fsutil do not provide such informations (As far as I know) :( // * edit: fsutil fsinfo drivetype X: return Fixed drive for a USB drive